# Solidity how to validate calldata decodes to a paticular struct

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decode, smartcontracts, abi

I have an interface in solidity which looks like so, I would like my call to revert if the calldata passed isn't of a specific type

```
// Resolver interface
interface IResolver {
    // Pass payment info as calldata only the manager should have the right to update it
    function resolve(uint256 amount, ResolverOptions calldata resolverOptions) external returns (uint256);

    // Reverts if the calldata passes is not a proper struct
   function validateAdditionalCalldata(bytes calldata additionalCalldata) external view;
}
```

I've created a class to implement this here:

```
struct fooResolverOptions {
    address[] fooAddresses; 
    uint256[] fooAmounts; 
}

contract FooResolver is IResolver {

    // Validate the additional calldata passed to the resolver contract
    function validateAdditionalCalldata(bytes calldata additionalCalldata) view external {
        // Convert the additional calldata to bytes memory
        bytes memory additionalCalldataMemory = additionalCalldata;

        // Decode the additional calldata as a FooResolverOptions struct
        FooResolverOptions memory fooOptions;
        bool success = abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, fooOptions);
    

        // Check if the decode was successful
        require(success, "Invalid additional calldata");
    }
}
```

None of the Way's I've tried to decode work:

```
bool success = abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, fooOptions);
```

this way claims there is no return value from decode.

```
FooResolverOptions memory fooOptions;
abi.decode(additionalCalldata, fooOptions);
```

This way claims it wants a tuple of types. How do I decode a struct data, and validate it succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity currently (v0.8) doesn't support dynamic arguments in `abi.decode()`, so you'll need to write logic that validates against predefined set of types.

---

`bytes calldata additionalCalldata` in your example is an array of bytes, so `abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, <types>);` tries to decode the binary to whatever `<types>` you pass. If the input fits the type length, it will simply decode the value to the type.

Example where the value fits into both `bool` and `address` types, so both operations succeed:

```
function validateAdditionalCalldata() pure external returns (bool, address) {
    bytes memory additionalCalldataMemory = hex"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
    bool decoded1 = abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, (bool));
    address decoded2 = abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, (address));

    return (decoded1, decoded2);
}
```

When the value doesn't fit the type, it throws an exception. Uncaught exception effectively reverts the transaction or the call. However, you can use `try` / `catch` to catch the exception.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract FooResolver {
    function validateAdditionalCalldata() external view returns (bool, address) {
        // does not fit `bool` but still fits `address`
        bytes memory additionalCalldataMemory = hex"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002";

        bool decoded1;
        try this.decodeToBool(additionalCalldataMemory) returns (bool decodedValue) {
            decoded1 = decodedValue;
        } catch {
            decoded1 = false;
        }

        address decoded2 = abi.decode(additionalCalldataMemory, (address));

        return (decoded1, decoded2);
    }

    // workaround - try/catch can be currently (v0.8) used on external function calls - but not on native function calls
    function decodeToBool(bytes memory data) external pure returns (bool) {
        return abi.decode(data, (bool));
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, so just for clarification when you mean fits, you're referring to whether the hex will overflow that type?

e.g abi.decode does not validate the length of the call data to verify it matches? e.g sincy it takes in an array of types, will it assume you've ommited a portion for decoding or it should always match the length of the types your trying to decode?

Comment: @RitzyDev Both "whether the hex will overflow that type" and the expected byte array length: 1) There's effectively only `0` and `1` in `bool` so you cannot assign it a `2`... 2) Fixed-size arrays have predetermined byte length in the datatype declaration (e.g. `address[2]` is expected to take exactly 2 slots of 32 bytes). Dynamic-size arrays (e.g. `address[]`) follow a pattern in the data that uses 2 slots for empty arrays or at least 3 slots for arrays with values. The second slot value holds the length of the data, so it can also be used for validation.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an resources where I can research this more, I looked into the solidity docs but I don't see much mention of how abi.encode works

Comment: @RitzyDev There's a dedicated section in the docs describing how the ABI encoding works, including dynamic types with examples: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html

Comment: hmm, I was looking at that, documentation is unclear, it doesn't really explictly state what will throw errors.  Thanks for the info though

Comment: Are you sure what you said is correct? I attempted to create a test for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75012873/validate-calldata-is-encoded-properly-in-abi and it still return properly

Comment: @RitzyDev Great catch. It errored for me when the data was shorter than expected: `abi.decode(hex"0001", (bool));` ... But when the input is longer, it only trims the data but doesn't error: `abi.decode(hex"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", (bool));`